# Request method 'POST' not supported when deleting object from ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

In my Spring application, I have a ManyToMany relationship between a User and an Area, where a User can save an Area to their ArrayList of Area objects. The user can look at their profile and see the areas they have saved in the form of a table on a jsp page. I have a header value in the table for the area name and the rows underneath will display each area in the users ArrayList of Area objects, a link to view the area on a Google Map, and a button to delete the area from their ArrayList.

```
        // Loop to go through the ArrayList of Areas
        <c:forEach var="o" items="${savedAreas}">
        <tr>
            // Display the name of the area
            <td width="10%" height="50"><c:out value="${o.areaName}" /></td>

            // View area on the map
            <a href = "welcome"> View on the map</a></td>

            // Button to pass the particular area object to the "deletearea" 
            // method in the Controller in the Spring application to run the 
            // delete method and remove the area object from the ArrayList
            <td width="3%" height="50"  class="tg-yw4l">      
                 <form th:action="@{/deletearea}" method="post" th:object="${area}">

                <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
              </form>
            </td>
         </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

The area object is supposed to be passed to the following method in the Controller.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/deletearea", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String deleteArea(@Valid Area area, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

      // Gets the current logged in user
      Authentication loggedInUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      String username = loggedInUser.getName(); // Authentication for 

      //Finds the user details in the database
      User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

      // Calls deleteArea from User Class and deletes area object from 
      // Arralist. Will include this method below
      user.deleteArea(area);

     // Saves update to user
      userRepository.save(user);


      //Simple print debug
      System.out.println(user + " deleted : " + area);

      // Refresh the jsp page
      return "savedAreas";
}
```

deleteArea called in the method in the Controller. It's from the User Object class.

```
    public void deleteArea(Area area) {
    if (!savedAreas.isEmpty()){
        savedAreas.remove(area);
    }
}
```

The problem is I'm getting the following error when I press the delete button.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported
```

Would anyone have any suggstions as to how I might fix this? Cheers

Comment: in debugging do you even hit this endpoint?

Comment: I did have a simple print debug in the controller method but it didn't print anything in the console in Eclipse. I've updated the question with the debug. Cheers